# How do I integrate Wordpress into Magento?

Tags: wordpress, magento

I'm using Xampp on my Windows(Localhost) where do I have to save the Wordpress file? (htdocs?) I can't get a database connection with fishpig although I already installed Wordpress.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While integrting Wordpress to Magento you can able to take help from [Magento comunity](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration-3795.html) 
or check with have you placed your Wordpress folder in proper place(htcdocs) And check with DB credentials you proper inserted into wp_config.php file

Answer (score 0):

Place your wordpress folder in htdocs folder and make sure you have added correct database details in wp_config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension to integrate wordpress into Magento.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration-3795.html

Install wordpress into your magento root and configure properly. Follow all steps provided by extension.